# Jquery Mobile 'data-role="page"' concept - Jqplot

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, jqplot

I am populating a chart with user Input. And refreshing it whenever the values change.
It work's in the same page, although when i try to put the chart in another data-role page, it doesnt work.
Is there something more to consider when changing the page? I am not sure if i was clear.. Here is my code:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="charttest">      
      <input id="userchart">
     <input id="userchart2">
     <input type="button" id="savechart" value="Save"/>
      <a href="#chartresult" data-role="button" data-icon="">Chart Restult</a>
  </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="chartresult">
      <div id="chartdiv" style="width:30%;"></div>            
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#savechart').click(function(){
num = $('#userchart');
num2 = $('#userchart2');
tochart = num.val();
tochart2 = num2.val();
chartingg();
});
function chartingg(){
     $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

    var s1 = [tochart, tochart2];
    var ticks = ['Teste', 'Teste 2'];   

    var plot = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1], {

     seriesDefaults: {renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
     axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
      ticks:ticks
       }

      }
     });

     plot.data = [s1];
                plot.replot({resetAxes:true});

    }

});
```

If you change the chartdiv to #charttest, it works...Why doesnt work crossing pages?

Comment: Try using $(document).on('pageinit', function(){

}); instead of $(document).ready(.. since jQuery Mobile loads pages using Ajax.

Comment: that should work on phone gap?

Comment: I did that but, it doesnt work still... i also put a link to chartresult with $.mobile.changePage( , {reloadPage:true}); Maybe is a JQPlot issue?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console (Chrome: Settings button / tools/ Javascript Console, IE9 F12 / console tab) for error messages?